# web browser API calls using flask returns 405

Tags: json, curl

I am new to flask and trying to make a simple json request and i've tried using curl via cmd:

```
curl -d "{35465460:55}" 127.0.0.1:5000/post
```

Returns:

> *Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)*

so I tried:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5000/post?data={1:1}
```

returns:

> *The method is not allowed for the requested URL.*

the code i'm using for the app.py is:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

randomnumber = 0
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    randomnumber = random.randrange(0,100)
    return 'Hello, World! Your random number is: ' + str(randomnumber)
@app.route('/post', methods=["GET","POST"])
def testpost():
    input_json = request.get_json(force=True)
    dictToReturn = {'text':input_json['text']}
    return jsonify(dictToReturn)
```

So my question is why can't I seem to get the return json data?

Answer (score 0):

[JSON does not support integers as keys](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4) - keys must be strings.

It is inadvisable to include the HTTP method name in the route path - it does not scale well, and it is confusing when you allow multiple methods for a route that is named after a different method.

You can use `-X POST` with curl to make it submit a POST instead of a GET (which is the default method).